# Functional calculus for bounded normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding a property from the continuous (or Borel) functional calculus. Indeed, if $N$ is a bounded normal operator on a Hilbert space, then for any $f$ (continuous or Borel on the spectrum of $N$) we have
$$[f(N)]^*=\overline{f}(N)$$.

I could see from this that $f(N)$ is always a self-adjoint operator whenever $f$ is real-valued. This is, however, not consistent just e.g. with $f(x)=x^2$ as $N^2$ need not be self-adjoint if $N$ is normal (e.g. consider $N=2i I$). Please help me as I think I'm lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example with the  $f(x)=x^2$ does not fit into the picture, such $f$ acts $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$; for example take $x= 1+i$, then $f(x) = (1+i)^2 = 2i \not \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I got it better now...cheers

Answer (score 1):

By the Spectral Theorem, for any bounded Borel function $f$,
$$
         f(N)=\int_{\sigma}f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
          (f(N)x,y) 
       & = \overline{\int_{\sigma}\overline{f(\lambda)}d(E(\lambda)y,x)} \\
       & = \overline{(\overline{f}(N)y,x)} \\
       & = (x,\overline{f}(N)y)
\end{align}
Because this holds for all $x,y$, then $f(N)^*=\overline{f}(N)$.

**Other Part of your Question:** The function $f(z)=x^2$, i.e., $f(z)=\Re(z)^2$, would give you a selfadjoint operator $f(N)$. But $f(z)=z^2$ would not unless the spectrum is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, which is the case where $N=N^*$. To say that a function is real in this context means that it assumes real values on the spectrum $\sigma(N)$, which may not be real for a general normal operator.

Comment: So this is true, i.e. whenever $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$, then $f(N)$ is self-adjoint if $f$ is real-valued? In particular, is there an easy proof for the polynomial case?

Comment: @user326852 : What form would a polynomial take that is real on $\sigma(N)$, assume $\sigma(N)$ is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$. You could start with a diagonal matrix with complex entries on the diagonal. Map it through a function that maps the eigenvalues to real values. That gives you a real diagonal matrix.

Comment: I was talking about the infinite dimensional setting...

Comment: @user326852 : I'm using the spectral theorem. That's any dimension. Just giving you some ideas with the previous comment.